# What is a Makefile.inc?

Tags: make, gnu

I have a basic questions as to if some Makefile includes a Makefile.inc.
Generally what commands/configurations/rules go into the Makefile.inc ?

Any pointers would be useful.

thank you.

-AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  I've seen a makefile include `<system>.inc` files for system specific settings.  Before you compile, you need to make sure that the correct `.inc`  is used for the system that you are on.

It is also common to have project settings in `.inc` files, when there are multiple sub-makefiles for a project (one per directory).

It is also used to share common makefile code across different projects.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the programmer who wrote this make file.

Normally, a Makefile.inc file contains a common set of definitions and macros that are used across more than one installation. This way, they are more easily and centrally maintained.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a text file whose extension as per 'just convention' is set as inc rather than txt.

**Why?** - Just to identify that the file is to be used for importing common variables and functions.

inc files are not language-specific, they are simply text files and can have any filename.

In your case - the programmer must have named Makefile.inc arbitrarily to say that it has common var and functions defined to be included in his actual Makefile.

Syntax: include < filename>.inc